# Good length for answer, fidelity to question

Tags: discussion, support, policy, answer-quality

Shalom leChachmey Mi Yodeya.

I will spend a few minutes to ask about aesthetics and proportions of Q&A

I want to know if there is a standard concerning the length of answer or question. A question has many dimensions, the need of the author, but sometimes the question is multiple. An answer can choose an interesting part of a question and explain this.

Particularly, we see complex questions that need comprehensive and methodological presentation, introduction and development.

Some questions ask about simple but lengthy topics.

Obviously a quick and clear answer is the best. Personally I am confronted with an answer that I feel incomplete but still too lenghty. ([here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/69847/different-pesach-offerings)) 
and with another that I feel good in length but not very technically correct ([here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/69905/do-any-movements-forgo-the-seven-clean-days/69911#69911)) and one that become very length to avoid ambiguities([here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/70340/why-only-2-matzos-used-for-seder-by-the-vilna-gaon/70360#70360))
Paul Valery says "Tout ce qui est simple est faux, mais tout ce qui ne l'est pas est inutilisable." ("All which is simple is false, but all which is not it is unusable."). This statement in so good for a Q&A website!

BTW I ask myself what is the adapted format of the Q&A in Mi Yodeya, e.g. [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/69895/giyores-marrying-cohen-and-their-offspring) is a big topic and [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/69907/can-a-torah-be-made-using-parchment-from-a-neveilah-or-treifa)

1. In other words, what is the maximum and minimum number of characters for an answer?
2. Is it allowed to re-define a question and to follow the re-definition for the answer
3. I ame very curious to know the guidance of old timers

I have some Hava-Aminot. 60 lines is correct, we can cut one piece of  question an treat it independently, There is a need for an equivalent to "code review", as "maamar review". I am curious to see the result al Agada shel Pessach. Very short answers are often good. (Sometime one reference is sufficient).
 I note a general tendency to answer into the comment-rubric. It is not an hazard, may be less appealing and good teruts for shortness.